# fb like button inside maps api infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, facebook-like, infowindow

got the following problem as stated in topic:
How can I put the like button inside an info-window which content is loadad via ajax?

As I guess when loading the script in "main" page with map, doesn't trigger it because the content inside the info-window is not as DOM element?

thx in advance!

Comment: The content of an `InfoWindow` is a DOM element, so you shouldn't have any problem including whatever type of button you like. If you include some code, a link, or maybe setup a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), it will allow everyone to take a look and give you hand.

Comment: Sry can't show you the whole code. here is a part responsible for loading content: 
`$.ajax({
url: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/maps/single/'+numer ,

  success: function(data){

   infowindow.setContent(data);
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
 });`     It simply loads a page with ajax and puts it content inside info window

Comment: Assuming the ajax call runs correctly, that `data` contains valid markup, that `infowindow`, `map`, and `marker` are in scope, the code looks essentially correct. It should load the content into the InfoWindow and then display the InfoWindow. Are you seeing errors?

Comment: there are no errors. markup is correct, visible in tree when inspecting but not hooked with js.
when i put `<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script> 

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.favoritebd.com" data-send="false" 
data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>` on my page it works great, but when in infowindow